# Rxjs Observable not emitting latest data to all the subscribers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have declared a subject in service and tried to push the response got by making a GET call to back end using "subject.next()"..also assigned an observable for the subject using "subject.asObservable()" and subscribed to the observable in two different components(parent and router outlet child). Problem is that the observable is emitting the new value for only one subscriber not for two subscribers.

***service***

```
subject = new Subject<any>();
  observable = this.subject.asObservable();


 public getDetails(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.url.concat(id))
      .pipe(map(data => this.extractDetails(data),
            catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
  }
 public extractDetails(data){
    this.subject.next(data);
    return data;
  }
```

**Parent component**

```
ngOnInIt(){
 this.hitUrl();

}
getDetails(){
    this.service.observable.subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    )
  }

  hitUrl(id: string) {
    this.service.getDetails(id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => 
        if(!!data){
            console.log(data);
            this.getDetails();
          }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

**router-outlet child component**

```
ngOnInIt(){
 this.hitUrl();

}
getDetails(){
    this.service.observable.subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    )
  }

  hitUrl(id: string) {
    this.service.getDetails(id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => 
        if(!!data){
            console.log(data);
            this.getDetails();
          }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

In the components hitUrl() also triggers when a call to action is performed then i need that observable should emit latest data to both the subscribers(if call to action is performed from parent or router outlet child).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing concepts.
In your `service.getDetails` function, you are returning a new observable each time the function is called. So, your `observable` attribute is not used. 
You should export only the `observable` attribute and keep the `getDetails` private, calling that function only to fetch the data.

### How to create a service cache

#### BehaviorSubject

You can use BehaviorSubject, a variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to.

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
private observable = this.subject.asObservable();

  public getDetails(id) {
    if (!this.observable) {
      this.loadData();
    }
    return this.observable;
  }

  private loadData() {
    this.http.get(this.url.concat(id))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.subject.next(data);
    })
    this.observable = this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

#### shareReplay

The best way is using rxjs **shareReplay**. This operator returns an Observable that shares a single subscription to the underlying source. In other words, turns our observable hot.

```js
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;
class Service { 

  private _data$: Observable<YourType>;

  get data(): Observable<YourType> {
    if (!this._data$) {
      this._data$ = anyHttpCall()
        .pipe(shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: CACHE_SIZE })
      );
    }
    return this._data$;
  }
}
```

The **bufferSize** determines the maximum element count of the replay buffer, that is the number of elements that are cached and replayed for every subscriber.

This post explains this very good: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html